# Writing the Output of an Operating System Command to the Console

Tags: java, command-line, command, runtime, executable

I want to execute an operating system command in Java, and then print out it's returned value. Like this:

This is what I am trying...

```
String location_of_my_exe_and_some_parameters = "c:\\blabla.exe /hello -hi";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location_of_my_exe_and_some_parameters);
```

I tried putting a System.out.print() on the beginning of my Runtime... line, but it failed. Because, apparently, [`getRuntime()` returns a `Runtime` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime%28%29).

Now, the problem is, when I execute the "blabla.exe /hello -hi" command in command line, I got a result like: "You executed some command, hurray!". But, in Java, I got nothing.

I tried putting the return value into a `Runtime` object, to an `Object` object. However, they both failed. How can I accomplish this?

**Problem Solved - this is my solution**

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(location, args).start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `Runtime.exec(...)` returns a `Process` object. You can use this object to capture its input stream and retrieve whatever it prints to the standard output:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location_of_my_exe_and_some_parameters);
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

// read process output from is
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for being kind, polite and fast.

Comment: @John Doe: Make sure to mark the answer that was the most helpful to you as accepted for future readers to find it fast.

Comment: I think I can't mark or vote. I don't have sufficient "karma" for that.

Comment: @John Doe: You need 15 to vote, but you can mark at any score, even 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output of a command using this:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process pr = rt.exec(command);
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
 String line=null;

 while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
    log.info(line);
 }
  //This will wait for the return code of the process
 int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

UseProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.

Like:

`Process process = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\blabla.exe","param1","param2").start();`

**Answer:**

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\blabla.exe","/hello","-hi").start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));
```